# why this error always on? Identifier not found or not unique

Tags: solidity, smartcontracts

```
    pragma solidity ^0.8.6;
contract mycontract{

address owner;
string name;
bool visible;
uint16 count;

constructor ()public {
    owner=msg.sender;
    
}

function changname (stringmemory _name) public returns (stringmemory){
    if(msg.sender==owner){
        name=_name;
        return "sucsesss";
        }else{
            return "acsess denid";
    }
}

function showname () view public returns(stringmemory){
    return name;
    
}
}
```

hey guuys i write this codes down but i gut the blow error what should i do now pls help me thank you

```
this project its belong to my university and if i lost in it i will fail my exam and im bechokh miram toro khoda komak konid thank you
```

i got some warning too what is this ?
SPDX license identifier not provided in source file. Before publishing, consider adding a comment containing "SPDX-License-Identifier: " to each source file. Use "SPDX-License-Identifier: UNLICENSED" for non-open-source code. Please see https://spdx.org for more information.
--> browser/test.sol

```
    DeclarationError: Identifier not found or not unique.
--> browser/test.sol:14:21:
|
14 | function changname (stringmemory _name) public returns (stringmemory){
| ^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

Comment: You have a typo in the code. Replace `stringmemory` (together) with `string memory`. This solves the error.

Answer (score 0):

It has a couple of bugs in its code.

1. builder visibility is not required
2. in the parameters of its functions it has a bad type
   'stringmemory' the variable would be type 'sting' and it would be read from memory.

In this way your code would look like this:

```
pragma solidity ^0.8.6;
contract mycontract{

    address owner;
    string name;
    bool visible;
    uint16 count;

constructor () {
    owner=msg.sender;    
}

    function changname (string memory _name) public returns (string memory){
        if(msg.sender==owner){
            name=_name;
            return "sucsesss";
        }else{
            return "acsess denid";
        }
    }

    function showname () view public returns(string memory){
        return name;
    }
}
```